# jquery autocomplete works after backspace

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Sometimes autocomplete display previous value or none even if data is present in sourceData. When i press backspace then it works well. Is any method we need to apply on it at the time of set data to source, can you please help me to solve this problem. I have following code:

```
function BindData(data) {
    var arrData = data.split("@@");
    var sourceData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
            var arrValue = arrData[i].split("||");
            sourceData.push({ "value": arrValue[0], "label": arrValue[1] });
        }
    $(function () {

        var Type = $('#slctType').val();
        if (Type == "Case") {
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: sourceData,
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // manually update the textbox
                    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // manually update the textbox and hidden field
                    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                    ID = ui.item.value;
                    //alert(ui.item.value);
                    //$("#autocomplete2-value").val(ui.item.value);
                }
            }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

                var arrV = item.value.split("-");
                var listItem = $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append("<a class = '" + arrV[1] + "Color'>" + item.label + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);


                return listItem;
            };
        }
        else
        {
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: sourceData,
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // manually update the textbox
                    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                    event.preventDefault();
                    // manually update the textbox and hidden field
                    $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                    ID = ui.item.value;
                    //alert(ui.item.value);
                    //$("#autocomplete2-value").val(ui.item.value);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nothing looks out of place. Any errors or alerts from console? Any sample data we can use for testing?

Comment: data is in this format:
data="2299||Final Testing@@2262||Soft Client testing@@2359||Testing for Link Child Entity@@2385||Testing Previous Company Name"
data="2385||Testing Previous Company Name"

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason the data is in such a complex format? Would it be possible to receive a JSON string? Also I see you have `data` listed twice in your comment, is this correct? Is `data` overwritten?

Comment: Also, when looking at your code, `sourceData` is out of scope. You cannot define a variable in one function and use it in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to identify all the potential issues. I will start with a working example and try to offer some of the major items that had to be overcome.

Please review: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Please make sure to provide a MCVE when posting future questions.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/nwkdaeuo/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="slctType">Type: </label>
  <select id="slctType">
    <option>Case</option>
    <option>Not Case</option>
  </select>
  <label for="tags">Stage: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

You did not provide any HTML in your example code, so I created some based on the jQuery Demo and the details in your code.

**CSS**

```
.redColor {
  color: red;
}
```

Again, you did not provide any CSS example code, so I had to make some assumptions.

**JavaScript**

```
var myData = "2299||Final Testing@@2262||Soft Client testing@@2359||Testing for Link Child Entity@@2385||Testing Previous Company Name@@2385||Testing Previous Company Name@@9999-red||Test Case";

function BindData(data) {
  console.log("Initial Data:", data);
  var a = data.split("@@");
  console.log("First Split:", a);
  var s = [];
  if (a.length < 1) {
    return false;
  }
  $.each(a, function(i, v) {
    console.log("Item:", v);
    var av = v.split("||");
    s.push({
      "value": av[0],
      "label": av[1]
    });
  });
  console.log("Final Data:", s);
  return s;
}

$(function() {
  var sourceData = BindData(myData);
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: sourceData,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).val(ui.item.label);
      ID = ui.item.value;
    }
  }).autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    var listItem = $("<li>");
    var arrV = "";
    if ($("#slctType").val() == "Case" && item.value.indexOf("-") > 0) {
      arrV = item.value.split("-");
      console.log("Case:", arrV);
      listItem
        .data("item-autocomplete", item)
        .append("<div><span class='" + arrV[1] + "Color'>" + item.label + "</div>");
    } else {
      listItem
        .data("item-autocomplete", item)
        .append("<div>" + item.label + "</div>");
    }
    listItem.appendTo(ul);
    return listItem;
  };
});
```

So to make better use of the `BindData()` function, I had it return the resulting array of objects. This allows you to pass it the data and return a proper array for Autocomplete. It is not clear where this data is provided from. If it's an API, you could possible call it via AJAX.

The `if` statement up front had to be moved. The logic there would have assumed the user would never change the `slctType` option. Again, without proper examples, I had to made a lot of guesses. I moved this logic into the `_renderItem` callback. This way the rendering can be created as needed in case the user changes the option.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response @twisty. I have used Ajax inside Autocomplete source method other than passing and adding data to sourceData and it works

Comment: Glad to hear. If my post helped, hope you will up vote and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

All I did was change my HTML field like this:

FROM

```
onchange="CallMyFunction();"
```

TO

```
ontextchanged="CallMyFunction();"
```

It now presents results while you are typing and not only when pressing backspace.